# How can it be possible Creating instance of interface in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the following code and a little bit confused. After some Googling, I found Anonymus Classes In OOP. But can't understand why in this code they declared Sorting object and calling an instance of MergeSort with `sorting = new MergeSort();` ? Can someone explain to me?

```
interface Sorting {
   List sort(List list);
}
class MergeSort implements Sorting {
    public List sort(List list) {
// sort implementation
        return list;
    }
}
class QuickSort implements Sorting {
    public List sort(List list) {
// sort implementation
        return list;
    }
}
class DynamicDataSet {
    Sorting sorting;
    public DynamicDataSet() {
        sorting = new MergeSort();
    }
// DynamicDataSet implementation
}
class SnapshotDataSet {
    Sorting sorting;
    public SnapshotDataSet() {
        sorting = new QuickSort();
    }
// SnapshotDataSet implementation
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times..

Answer (score 0):

Because `MergeSort` *is* a `Sorting` implementation.

That whay you will only be able to use what the interface specifiebut it will be easier to change the implmentation you want to use. This is why it is a good practice to only handle interfaces.

See also [this chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) of Oracles's doc.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `Sorting object` is used to refer `MergeSort()` and `QuickSort()` because they have implemented Sorting interface. Interface directly can not be used to create a Object you can only use a reference of interface.